# How can I deal with weighted sample on python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I created this data as an example.

There is 2 guys and 1 girl in the sample. However it was expected that the number of guys and girls were equal. Then, I defined "weights" for each row that makes the number of guys and girls become equal.

Then, I want to use this weighted sample to create a histogram of age.

I wish I could find a good library to deal with this kind of situation.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = [[10, 'M', 0.75], [15, 'F', 1.50], [20, 'M', 0.75]]

DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Age', 'gender', 'Weight'])

sns.distplot(DataFrame['Age'], bins=5)
```

I expected a histogram which the biggest column is for the Age=15 (because the girls have the biggest weight). But, I got 3 equal columns for values Age=[10,15,20].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `weights` parameter for Matplotlib's [Histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [[10, 'M', 0.75], [15, 'F', 1.50], [20, 'M', 0.75]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['age', 'gender', 'weight'])
plt.hist(df["age"], weights=df["weight"]);
```

[image]

With more data this will look nicer.

Comment: Thank you, I found this pyreadstat library which really improves the work with survey data.

Also, now I'm using this function to work with frequencies with weighted data.

def weighted_freq(var, weight):
    cross = pd.Series(df[[var,weight]].groupby(var).sum()[weight])/df[weight].sum()
    labeled = cross.index.map(name[var])
    values = 100*cross.values
    tab = pd.DataFrame({'Labels': labeled, 'Frequency': values})
    return(tab)